# Volley post request 415 error

Tags: android, json, http-headers, android-volley

API response for the POSt request using volley gives me 415 error - There was a problem with the requests Content-Type:   Expected 'application/json'.

The issue is not with API because if we do not use Volley or use browser rest client we get proper response.

This is the code used

```
 VolleyRequestManager<test> volleyRequestManager =
            new VolleyRequestManager<>(Request.Method.POST, url,    requestBody, test.class,
                    Utility.getBearerAuthHeader(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            Constants.RequestKey.CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON), listener, errorListener
            );

    VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext())
            .addToRequestQueue(volleyRequestManager, tag);
```

for request body params,Jsonobject is created and add all the values to this and converts this to string

```
  JSONObject params = new JSONObject();  
  params.toString()
```

please help.

Comment: HTTP 415 means Unsupported media type, check your http header

Comment: Yeah , that i understood. Tired with both application/json and "application/json; charset=utf8"

Comment: @TechnoCRAP: Any updates?